# ASP.net hyperlink in email

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm pulling a hyperlink from a SQL db and trying to embed it in an email programmatically as follows:

```
        Dim dv As System.Data.DataView = CType(SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), System.Data.DataView)
        ''Add Ticket URL and comments to answers dictionary
        Dim emailMessage As New MailMessage("donotreply@myemail.com", "me@myemail.com")
        emailMessage.Body = dv.Item(0).Item(1).ToString <--Location of email
```

Example of data being pulled from db:

```
<a href=http://www.google.com>My email link</a>
```

I'm trying to get it to show up as a hyper link an email, but instead it displays the full html as above.  I've tried HTMLDecode, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Try emailMessage.isBodyHTML property